# Split a file into two

Tags: text-processing, awk, split, csplit

I have a big file and need to split into two files. Suppose in the first file the 1000 lines should be selected and put into another file and delete those lines in the first file.

I tried using `split` but it is creating multiple chunks.

Comment: Did you check `split --help`?

Comment: Yes i have checked it, but is creating multiple files which doesn't need to me.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use `head` and `tail`:

```
$ head -n 1000 input-file > output1
$ tail -n +1001 input-file > output2
```

That will put the first 1000 lines from `input-file` into `output1`, and all lines from 1001 till the end in `output2`

Comment: Funny thing that it works pretty well with 2GB+ files too!

Answer (score 30):

I think that `split` is you best approach.

Try using the `-l xxxx` option, where xxxx is the number of lines you want in each file (default is 1000).

You can use the `-n yy` option if you are more concerned about the amount of files created. Use `-n 2` will split your file in only 2 parts, no matter the amount of lines in each file.

You can count the amount of lines in your file with `wc -l  filename`. This is the 'wordcount' command with the lines option.

#### References

- `man split`
- `man wc`

Comment: This is how to split into a bunch of files with a fixed number of lines, or how to split evenly into a fixed number of files. Is there a way to split into one 1000-line file and one file with everything else? That's what he was asking for; I couldn't find it in the man page

Comment: You´re correct Michael. I think I took a simplistic view on the question. You solution is the best one in this case. Another way would be to use the 'sed' command: sed -n 1,1000 originalfile > first_1000_lines. sed '1,1000d' originalfile > remaining_lines.

Comment: Of course you could do `split -l 1000 bigfile && mv xaa piece1 && cat x?? > piece2 && rm x??`.

Comment: `split` is what I was looking for

Comment: split with both -l and -n options doesn't run ('split: cannot split in more than one way').
Question wanted file into 2 parts, but at a specific line:
split is the wrong tool for this job. csplit is the correct tool

Answer (score 19):

This is a job for [`csplit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html):

```
csplit -s infile 1001
```

will `s`ilently split `infile`, the first piece `xx00` - up to but not including line 1001 and the second piece `xx01` - the remaining lines.
You can play with the options if you need different output file names e.g. using `-f` and specifying a *prefix*:

```
csplit -sf piece. infile 1001
```

produces two files named `piece.00` and `piece.01`

---

With a smart `head` you could also do something like:

```
{ head -n 1000 > 1st.out; cat > 2nd.out; } < infile
```

Comment: Wow, it really *is* a job for `csplit`.  Very nice.  (I'm just reading through the list of POSIX commands and had enormous trouble wrapping my head around the `csplit` command's purpose at first.  Turns out it's really really simple.)  :)

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do what the question asks for, in one command:

```
awk '{ if (NR <= 1000) print > "piece1"; else print > "piece2"; }' bigfile
```

or, for those of you who really hate to type long, intuitively comprehensible commands,

```
awk '{ print > ((NR <= 1000) ? "piece1" : "piece2"); }' bigfile
```